# Download zip file being sent by server on client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an API that downloads multiple files from AWS S3, creates a zip which is saved to disk, and sends that zip back to the client. The API works, but I have no idea how to handle the response / download the zip to disk on the client side.

This is my API:

```
reports.get('/downloadMultipleReports/:fileKeys', async (req, res) => {

  var s3 = new AWS.S3();
  var archiver = require('archiver');

  const { promisify } = require('util');

  var str_array = req.params.fileKeys.split(',');

  console.log('str_array: ',str_array);

  for (var i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {

    var filename = str_array[i].trim();
    var filename = str_array[i];
    var localFileName = './temp/' + filename.substring(filename.indexOf("/") + 1);

    console.log('FILE KEY >>>>>>  : ', filename);

    const params = { Bucket: config.reportBucket, Key: filename };

    const data = await (s3.getObject(params)).promise();

    const writeFile = promisify(fs.writeFile);

    await writeFile(localFileName, data.Body);
  }

    // create a file to stream archive data to.
    var output = fs.createWriteStream('reportFiles.zip');
    var archive = archiver('zip', {
      zlib: { level: 9 } // Sets the compression level.
    });

    // listen for all archive data to be written
    // 'close' event is fired only when a file descriptor is involved
    output.on('close', function() {
      console.log(archive.pointer() + ' total bytes');
      console.log('archiver has been finalized and the output file descriptor has closed.');
    });

    // This event is fired when the data source is drained no matter what was the data source.
    // It is not part of this library but rather from the NodeJS Stream API.
    // @see: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end
    output.on('end', function() {
      console.log('Data has been drained');
    });

    // good practice to catch warnings (ie stat failures and other non-blocking errors)
    archive.on('warning', function(err) {
      if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
        // log warning
      } else {
        // throw error
        throw err;
      }
    });

    // good practice to catch this error explicitly
    archive.on('error', function(err) {
      throw err;
    });

    // pipe archive data to the file
    archive.pipe(output);

    // append files from a sub-directory, putting its contents at the root of archive
    archive.directory('./temp', false);

    // finalize the archive (ie we are done appending files but streams have to finish yet)
    // 'close', 'end' or 'finish' may be fired right after calling this method so register to them beforehand
    archive.finalize();

    output.on('finish', () => {

      console.log('Ding! - Zip is done!');

      const zipFilePath =  "./reportFiles.zip" // or any file format

      // res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/zip');

      fs.exists(zipFilePath, function(exists){

        if (exists) {     
          res.writeHead(200, {
            "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
            "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=" + "./reportFiles.zip"
          });
          fs.createReadStream(zipFilePath).pipe(res);

        } else {
          response.writeHead(400, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
          response.end("ERROR File does not exist");
        }

      });
    });

  return;
});
```

And this is how I am calling the API / expecting to download the response:

```
  downloadMultipleReports(){

    var fileKeysString = this.state.awsFileKeys.toString();
    var newFileKeys = fileKeysString.replace(/ /g, '%20').replace(/\//g, '%2F');

    fetch(config.api.urlFor('downloadMultipleReports', { fileKeys: newFileKeys }))
    .then((response) => response.body())

    this.closeModal();
  }
```

How can I handle the response / download the zip to disk?

Comment: Opinions will vary, but I've had good results with: https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working for me:

Server side:

```
const zipFilePath =  "./reportFiles.zip";

      fs.exists(zipFilePath, function(exists){

        if (exists) {     
          res.writeHead(200, {
            "Content-Type": "application/zip",
            "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=" + "./reportFiles.zip"
          });
          fs.createReadStream(zipFilePath).pipe(res);

        } else {
          response.writeHead(400, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
          response.end("ERROR File does not exist");
        }

      });
```

Client side:

```
  downloadMultipleReports(){

    var fileKeysString = this.state.awsFileKeys.toString();
    var newFileKeys = fileKeysString.replace(/ /g, '%20').replace(/\//g, '%2F');

    fetch(config.api.urlFor('downloadMultipleReports', { fileKeys: newFileKeys }))
    .then((res) => {return res.blob()})
    .then(blob =>{
      download(blob, 'reportFiles.zip', 'application/zip');
      this.setState({isOpen: false});
    })
  }
```